# Highcharts in polar mode: line does not look like a function

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highcharts in polar mode. I am using spline but it is rendered as a linear spline, rather than a polar one.
Please see the attached picture to compare what I want (red) vs what I get (black).

How can I solve? Thanks

[Bad polar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dORiZ.png)

Comment: You'll have to be a lot more specific about what you want, and what the problem is. Give a live example, and/or some code, and describe what it is about the black line that is wrong (and which black line are we talking about?), and which red line is it that illustrates what you do want? And what 'function' are you trying to illustrate?

Comment: Hi, please check this out, where I compare with a linear graphic: [sample](http://imgur.com/a/uO2UW)

Comment: I don't know if I understand still, but, it seems like part of the problem is the spline functionality itself, rather than the polar aspect? In that case...use a regular line instead.

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle with sample data?